# On a Craft 3 multi-site, how can I setup an Entries field to select entries from other sites?

Tags: multi-site, entries-field

On my primary site on a Craft 3 multi-site, I have an Entries field used to add links to other sites' entries. These entries are from Channels / Stuctures that are using the `Only save entries to the site they were created` in option. Within the entries pop up, I can't select entries from other sites: only the entries from the current site are shown and selectable.

I know I could use the `Relate entries from a specific site?` option to get entries from other sites, but this option only enable to select one site version, not all. In my case, I have so many sites that it would not be efficient to duplicate my Entries field.
I know I could add a simple URL field to copy the Entries URL instead, but this is not a safe way, and links could break easily.
I didn't found any existing plugin to achieve this.

What would be the best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `entries field` has an option `Show the site menu`, so this will give you a dropdown to select site when selecting entries. But the problem it doesn't save the site relation.

If your channels is only save to the site they created it should be fine, but when you querying the entries field you need to add site id to all if not the entries will not showing.

```
{% set entries = entry.entryField.siteId('*').all() %}
```